# Google play app change permissions

Tags: java, android, google-play

I have uploaded an application to google play, but it doesn't ask for permissions on install for some reason.

I have these permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can manually add these permissions via settings on the phone, other permissions do not show up, so I guess app is done correctly, though memory permission is disabled by default and user has to manually enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your module has its `targetSdkVersion` set to 23 or higher. In that case, permissions with a `protectionLevel` of `dangerous` — such as the two you are requesting — not only have to appear in the manifest, but have to be [requested at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).